# SVG формы периодически не прорисовываются

Tags: svg, svg-спрайт

Есть svg-лого у сайта, состоящее из изображения и текста. На сайте есть 6 страниц. При переходе со страницы на страницу случается так, что текст не отображается либо частично (не прорисовываются 1-2 буквы), либо полностью. Картинка при этом отображается всегда.
SVG текст преобразован в кривые path, и объединён тегом `<g></g>`. Всё изображение вставлено на сайт инлайново и подключается к хедеру посредством тега use. Так же на сайте есть пару svg-иконок и стрелочек, но с ними такого не происходит. И это случается только на внешнем хостинге, на локальном серваке такого не замечено. Какие могут быть причины такого поведения svg-текста? Есть какие-то предположения?

Comment: Без иконки мало что можно сказать. Или сайт покажите

Comment: @Altai код конечно нужен и ещё браузер какой используете? . Дело в том, что svg не во всех браузерах ведет себя одинаково.

Comment: Сорри что сразу не ответил, думал придут оповещения на имейл, но они пришли только сегодня. Проблема решилась переносом SVG-спрайта в хедер, до использования его элементов тегом use. Всем спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась переносом SVG-спрайта в хедер, до использования его элементов тегом use. Всем спасибо за внимание!

Comment: раз уж так получилось, отметьте свой ответ, как решение - галочка под треугольником. Это допускается правилами сайта. Хотя конечно жаль, что вы не показали кода, поверьте, - это не те грибные места, которые нужно скрывать. Это нужно для наполнения базы знаний сообщества. Наверняка, в будущем, у кого-нибудь будут точно такие же проблемы, а со слов довольно трудно понять все нюансы.